# Sequence numbers in Access 2016

Tags: ms-access

i am trying to have a auto sequence number in a field in Access, which in case that i delete a record the number tha i will delete will apply on the next record, ex. if i have 3 records 1,2,3 and delete the 3,  the next record i would like to take the 3 and not 4, i am using dmax... the code is

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
Νούμερο = DMax("Νούμερο", "Πίνακας1") + 1
End Sub
```

but it doesn't work. Νούμερο=field and πίνακας1=the table

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but try being a little more specific:

```vb
Private Sub Form_BeforeInsert(Cancel As Integer)
    Me!Νούμερο.Value = DMax("Νούμερο", "Πίνακας1") + 1
End Sub
```

Comment: It works here, so review your form as something else is going on.

Comment: ok, yes you are right, it works on the form, is it possible to work also when i insert a record on the table?

Comment: That could be a _data macro_ but I don't use these, so can't tell for sure.